# Data stage parallel job export options

Tags: data-warehouse, datastage, ibm-data-studio, istool

I am aware that in Datastage the parallel jobs (.pjb) or any other jobs can be exported to .dsx and .isx files. I wondered if I can simply export a .pjb file as is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say ' as is '  what are you trying to do ? 
if you are to move datastage code across different ds servers you would need to take an export. 
And export can either be a .dsx  .isx and .xml

Datastage also allows you to copy the design. which means selecting design stages using a mouse copying it and pasting it onto a different designer window. (but it is not recommended , since this would not bring in the dependednt components. )

Comment: when I say as is, what I meant is can I export and import a .pjb version by any means?